# Meteor accounts-password client-side account creation security

Tags: javascript, security, meteor, meteor-accounts, javascript-injection

I am creating a web app with Meteor and i am having some concerns about the security on account creation. I know i can fix this problem by using a Meteor method, but the advantage of doing this client-side is that you can log the user in instantly after the account is created.

I currently don't have anything validating my input to make it simple:

```
Template.register.events({
    'submit form': function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var userInfo = {
            email: e.target.registerEmail.value,
            password: e.target.registerPassword.value,
            password_confirmation: e.target.registerPasswordConfirmation.value
        };

        check(userInfo, {
            email: String,
            password: String,
            password_confirmation: String
        });

        //Do some checks on the passwords and email before trying to create account
        Accounts.createUser({
            email: userInfo.email,
            password: userInfo.password,
            profileComplete: false
        });

    }
});
```

This works great and it's the way that the accounts-ui package does it. The problem is that i can bypass any input validation (and i checked this on an app running just the accounts-ui and accounts-password package too) by simply writing a javascript command in the console like this:

```
Accounts.createUser({
    email: "NotAnEmail",
    password: "123"
});
```

And this will create a user with the email and password as shown and log them in. This seems like a huge flaw with the accounts-ui package, or mabey i am just missing something? Is there some way to still allow client-side account creation, while making sure you can't do any javascript injections from the console to bypass the input checks?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same concerns about the security i discovered that there is a Meteor hook which you can use to validate the input after the Accounts.createUser request has been sent. This is how my code looks, when i validate the email field only and also add the extra field profileComplete.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    if (! validateEmail(options.email))
        throw new Meteor.Error(400, 'There was an error processing your request');

    user.profileComplete = options.profileComplete;
    return user;
});
```

validateEmail is a custom function i defined and not a native Meteor function.